# Windows 10's desktop image turning all black

Tags: windows-10, desktop

Today i'm having a little problem with my Thinkpad t61 win10-upgraded pc.
The desktop's background at some points turns all black (this is not explorer.exe crashing, explorer is still alive). Then, after 2-5 minutes, if i update the desktop (e.g. drag&drop a file, press F5...) the background image returns back.
sometimes with an xp-like visual glitch.
I have disk spae running out, but i don't think that's related to this because 1GB of space is enough to display the desktop.
the file TranscodedWallpaper into `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`
exists.
does anyone knows why is this happening?
note that if i log on into the admin account this does not happens)

Comment: I know this behavior only in case the computer is running a screen sharing software like TeamViewer and somebody connects to it. For saving bandwidth screensharing software usually temporarily disables the background image.

Comment: I had a T61 from 2008 and it would not run Windows 10 because the video would not support Windows 10. That machine is end of life at this point

Comment: @John, no reason to discard hardware MS won't support; use another OS such as Ubuntu or Lubuntu, which run well on new *and* old boxes.

Comment: That machine (I had one as I noted) stretched from XP to Vista to Seven and to Eight but the video would not work in Windows 10 and there is no upgrade to the video on the Lenovo site

Comment: This machine born with win vista, has a core 2 duo T8100 x64, 8GB of DDR2 ram (2x4)(before they were 4), a 1024x768 display (and a 1280x1024 @75hz monitor attached) and an ssd. i can develop in unity3D with only a little lag